# i get error on apache start 'apache2: bad user name superkkt'

Tags: linux, apache

Whe I start apache

`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start` i get this error message

```
 root@h1975757:~# sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
 * Starting web server apache                                                                                                 
apache2: bad user name superkkt
```

I tried add apache2.conf

```
User www-data
Group www-data
```

no luck
file `envars` contains the same data

how to fix this?

root@h1975757:~# uname -a Linux  2.6.32-042stab078.27 #1 SMP Mon Jul 1 20:48:07 MSK 2013 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: Try http://serverfault.com or http://stackexchange.com

Comment: `grep -r superkkt /etc/apache2`

Comment: @Carlos Campderrós, I have tried this, no match

Answer (score 0):

first check your apache error_log file for more details.
And then look in the httpd.conf file for the line that starts with "User" that
defined the user superkkt that Apache is going switch to running as. Check that
the user is listed in a valid user on the server